# Why does Hibernate execute SQL update twice each time EntityManager#merge(T entity) is invoked when using Envers Auditing?

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, jpa, hibernate-envers

Why does Hibernate execute SQL update twice each time the web application invokes `EntityManager#merge(T entity)`?  I first noticed this when I observed that the database record's version will increment 1, 3, 5, ... instead of 1, 2, 3, ...

So first, I set a breakpoint in my IDE to verify that my application invokes `EntityManager#merge(T entity)` only one time.  Second, I set

```
<property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
```

in persistence.xml.  I was surprised to observe that the SQL update executes twice:

```
    Hibernate: 
    update
        applicationuser 
    set
        timestamp=?,
        userstamp=?,
        version=?,
        email=?
    where
        id=? 
        and version=?
    Hibernate:
        select
            nextval ('hibernate_sequence')
    Hibernate:
        insert
        into
            REVINFO
            (REVTSTMP, REV)
        values
            (?, ?)
    Hibernate:
        insert
        into
            applicationuser_AUD
            (REVTYPE, hashcode, timestamp, email, userstamp, id, REV)
        values
            (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
    Hibernate:
        update
            applicationuser
        set
            timestamp=?,
            userstamp=?,
            version=?,
            email=?
        where
            id=?
            and version=?
```

Why does the update statement get executed twice?  Does this have something to do with Hibernate Envers auditing the record?

UPDATE:  Here's the Java code:

```
    @Stateless
    @LocalBean
    @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED)
    public class UserService {

        @PersistenceContext EntityManager em;

        public User merge(@Nonnull User user) {
            return em.merge(user);
        }
    }
```

UPDATE:

Disabling auditing causes the problem to go away e.g. only one SQL `UPDATE` statement is executed upon invoking `EntityManager#merge(T entity)` after commenting out the `@Audited` annotation.  So it appears that Envers auditing is what is causing the double update. Is this expected behavior from Envers?  Why does Envers do the double update?  Can I make this stop without disabling Envers?

```
    //@Audited
    @Table(name="applicationuser")
    @Entity
    @XmlRootElement
    public class User {
        ...
    }
```

Comment: The sequence issue is separate from the update issue: The `select nextval` will update your sequence, if the value is then not used, it is placed back for later use.

Comment: I'm still unclear about why it executes UPDATE twice each time.  It seems that the sequence is working fine, so not sure why you would mention the sequence issue.

Comment: I mention the sequence issue because you mention it in your question: *I first noticed this when I observed that the database record's version will increment 1, 3, 5, ... instead of 1, 2, 3, ...*

Comment: Hmm.. sorry, still not following your line of thought.  My question was about version, not sequence.  Sequence only appears in SQL that I pasted to show what Hibernate is doing.  It appears to me that there is no issue with sequence.  The problem seems to be that the SQL UPDATE is executing twice, and each time the UPDATE executes the version increments.  I think SQL UPDATE should only be executing once.  If it executes once then version will increment one, which is what I would expect.  Instead, version increments two.  I think this is because UPDATE executes twice.

Comment: For the hibernate part you will have to post the relevant code to see if what might be happening, because it seems to be more then just the merge. For example: Do you have relations defined in your model?

Comment: I've added the Java code to my question.  Really, the only code is em.merge(user); Setting breakpoint there, and watching SQL code in logs. I do have relations between user and role, but no role is being updated in that one line of java code execution, and there is no SQL UPDATE of the role database table taking place when em.merge(user) executes. In other words, the SQL that I show in my question is exactly what runs. There's no reason I can understand why it SQL UPDATEs twice on applicationuser.

Comment: I see however in your trace that `REVINFO` and `applicationuser_AUD` get an insert. That is not visible in the `merge` statement, so most likely it is in your data model. You have a JPA embedded entity in this?

Comment: Nope, not using an embeddable class. Auditing comes for free with [Hibernate Envers](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/devguide/en-US/html/ch15.html). `org.hibernate.envers.Audited` tells Hibernate to insert new audit record into `applicationuser_AUD` on each update of `applicationuser` whereas `javax.persistence.Version` tells JPA to increment the `applicationuser` version field by 1 on each update. `REVINFO` is used by Envers for audit table, not version column. I think the problem is that JPA is updating `applicationuser` twice, as evidenced by SQL output.

Comment: Please disable Hibernate Envers and re-test to see what happens.

Comment: Well that certainly did make the extra `UPDATE` statement go away.  Now, the version increments as it should.  So the problem appears to caused by the use of Envers auditing in combination with JPA versioning.  I've updated the question to incorporate this new information.  Much gratitude!

Comment: I suggest you delete this question and post a new one: This one is now too deep in the bulk of questions to be noticed again.

Comment: I'm not sure what version of Envers you're using, but I certainly don't see this behavior on the 5.x releases.